# A Fast and Efficient way to create a matrix from a series of product

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, large-data

Ax, Ay, Az: [N-by-N]

B=AA      (a dyadic product)

It means :

```
B(i,j)= [Ax(i,j);Ay(i,j);Az(i,j)]*[Ax(i,j) Ay(i,j) Az(i,j)]
```

B(i,j) : a 3x3 matrix.
One way to construct B is:

```
N=2;
Ax=rand(N); Ay=rand(N); Az=rand(N);     %# [N-by-N]
t=1;
F=zeros(3,3,N^2);
for  i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        F(:,:,t)= [Ax(i,j);Ay(i,j);Az(i,j)]*[Ax(i,j) Ay(i,j) Az(i,j)];
        t=t+1;                          %# t is just a counter
    end
end
%# then we can write
B = mat2cell(F,3,3,ones(N^2,1));
B = reshape(B,N,N)'; 
B = cell2mat(B);
```

Is there a faster way for  when N is large.

Edit:

Thanks for your answer. (It's faster)
 Let's put:
 N=2;
 Ax=[1 2;3 4]; Ay=[5 6;7 8]; Az=[9 10;11 12];

```
B =

 1     5     9     4    12    20
 5    25    45    12    36    60
 9    45    81    20    60   100
 9    21    33    16    32    48
21    49    77    32    64    96
33    77   121    48    96   144
```

Run:
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

If I write :`P = Ai*Aj;` then

```
B  =

 7    19    31    15    43    71
23    67   111    31    91   151
39   115   191    47   139   231
10    22    34    22    50    78
34    78   122    46   106   166
58   134   210    70   162   254
```

That is defferent from above
A(:,:,1) deffer from [Ax(1,1) Ay(1,1) Az(1,1)]

Edit:

```
N=100;
Me      :Elapsed time is 1.614244 seconds.
gnovice :Elapsed time is 0.056575 seconds.
N=200;
Me      :Elapsed time is 6.044628 seconds.
gnovice :Elapsed time is 0.182455 seconds.
N=400;
Me      :Elapsed time is 23.775540 seconds.
gnovice :Elapsed time is 0.756682 seconds.
Fast!

rwong: B was not the same.
```

Edit:

After some modification for my application :
by gnovice codes

```
 1st code :  19.303310 seconds
 2nd code:  23.128920  seconds
 3rd code:  13.363585  seconds
```

It seems that any function calling like ceil,ind2sub ... make thw loops slow and shoud avoid if possible.

`symIndex` was interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple and general implementation that uses a single for loop to perform [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) and avoids dealing with 3-dimensional variables or reshaping:

```
%# General solution:
%# ----------------
B = cell(N);
for index = 1:N^2
  A = [Ax(index) Ay(index) Az(index)];
  B{index} = A(:)*A;
end
B = cell2mat(B);
```

**EDIT #1:**

In response to the additional question of how to reduce the number of calculations performed for a symmetric matrix `B`, you could use the following modified version of the above code:

```
%# Symmetric solution #1:
%# ---------------------
B = cell(N);
for index = find(tril(ones(N))).'  %'# Loop over the lower triangular part of B
  A = [Ax(index) Ay(index) Az(index)];
  B{index} = A(:)*A;
  symIndex = N*rem(index-1,N)+ceil(index/N);  %# Find the linear index for the
                                              %#   symmetric element
  if symIndex ~= index       %# If we're not on the main diagonal
    B{symIndex} = B{index};  %#   then copy the symmetric element
  end
end
B = cell2mat(B);
```

However, in such a case you may get better performance (or at least simpler looking code) by foregoing the linear indexing and using two for loops with subscripted indexing like so:

```
%# Symmetric solution #2:
%# ---------------------
B = cell(N);
for c = 1:N    %# Loop over the columns
  for r = c:N  %# Loop over a subset of the rows
    A = [Ax(r,c) Ay(r,c) Az(r,c)];
    B{r,c} = A(:)*A;
    if r ~= c           %# If we're not on the main diagonal
      B{c,r} = B{r,c};  %#   then copy the symmetric element
    end
  end
end
B = cell2mat(B);
```

**EDIT #2:**

The second symmetric solution can be further sped up by moving the diagonal calculation outside of the inner loop (removing the need for a conditional statement) and overwriting `A` with the result `A(:)*A` so that we can update the symmetric cell entry `B{c,r}` using `A` instead of `B{r,c}` (i.e. updating one cell with the contents of another appears to carry some extra overhead):

```
%# Symmetric solution #3:
%# ---------------------
B = cell(N);
for c = 1:N    %# Loop over the columns
  A = [Ax(c,c) Ay(c,c) Az(c,c)];
  B{c,c} = A(:)*A;
  for r = c+1:N  %# Loop over a subset of the rows
    A = [Ax(r,c) Ay(r,c) Az(r,c)];
    A = A(:)*A;
    B{r,c} = A;
    B{c,r} = A;
  end
end
B = cell2mat(B);
```

And here are some timing results for the 3 symmetric solutions using the following sample symmetric matrices `Ax`, `Ay`, and `Az`:

```
N = 400;
Ax = tril(rand(N));     %# Lower triangular matrix
Ax = Ax+triu(Ax.',1);  %'# Add transpose to fill upper triangle
Ay = tril(rand(N));     %# Lower triangular matrix
Ay = Ay+triu(Ay.',1);  %'# Add transpose to fill upper triangle
Az = tril(rand(N));     %# Lower triangular matrix
Az = Az+triu(Az.',1);  %'# Add transpose to fill upper triangle

%# Timing results:
%# --------------
%# Solution #1 = 0.779415 seconds
%# Solution #2 = 0.704830 seconds
%# Solution #3 = 0.325920 seconds
```

The big speed-up for solution 3 results primarily from updating the cell contents of `B` with the local variable `A` instead of updating one cell with the contents of another. In other words, copying cell contents with operations like `B{c,r} = B{r,c};` carries more overhead than I expected.

Comment: Thank alot gnovice.This is Outstanding! Is it possible in linear indexing that we say to the algorithem  calculate only half of the matrix when B is symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

```
A = cat(3, Ax, Ay, Az);   % [N-by-N-by-3]
F = zeros(3, 3, N^2);
for i = 1:3, 
  for j = 1:3,
    Ai = A(:,:,i);
    Aj = A(:,:,j);
    P = Ai(:) .* Aj(:);
    F(i,j,:) = reshape(P, [1, 1, N^2]);
  end
end

%# then we can write
B = mat2cell(F,3,3,ones(N^2,1));
B = reshape(B,N,N)'; 
B = cell2mat(B);
```

Comment: `P = Ai(:) * Aj(:); `--> `P = Ai * Aj; ` ?

Comment: @user784433: fixed. It should be elementwise multiply, resulting in a `[N^2, 1, 1]` vector. thanks.